# Highcharts custom events plugin right click event not firing

Tags: javascript, events, highcharts, contextmenu

http://jsfiddle.net/ovbpacrt/1/

I can't get the `contextmenu` event to fire on a right click in the above.

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(
{
   series:[
      {
         "data": data,
          type: 'pie',
          animation: false,
          point:{
              events:{
                  contextmenu: function (event) {
                      alert(this.id);
                  }
              }
          }          
      }
   ],
   "chart":{
      "renderTo":"container"
   },
});
```

If I change the `contextmenu` to `click` (and instead left click), then the event works correctly.

What maybe the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use raw github files because they will be blocked by CORS.

```
 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blacklabel/custom_events/master/js/customEvents.js with MIME type text/plain. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Try using a CDN https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/highcharts-custom-events@2.2.4/js/customEvents.min.js

Here you can learn a little more on how to bypass this without a CDN https://gist.github.com/jesperorb/6ca596217c8dfba237744966c2b5ab1e